# Fin plot installation and import issues

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, candlestick-chart, mplfinance

I have noted multiple questions regarding the outline usage and installation but as I lack sufficient rep.points, I am not allowed to ask questions on them, so my apologies if this is a duplicate question.

As a capstone project I am attempting to build a basic program that extracts financial data from yahoo finance and displays it to the user in graphical form (candlestick_OCHL).

I've initially started using mplfinance and although I've got relatively satisfactory results, finplot appears to offer a few more customisation options which I think could better represent the data in graphical form, namely aspects such as sub plotting(2:2) which I cant seem to do with mplfinanace.

Ive attempted to install finplot via cmd (below indicates windows ver. and python ver.), the finplt is 1.6

[image]

However when using jupyterlab the following issue continuously appears:

[image]

could anyone possibly advise a course of action, or if not is there a different module that can offer more customizations (sub plotting,axes-title,wick markers, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mplfinance provides two procedures for creating subplots.  One, called "Panels" requires the subplots to be stacked vertically, but is very simple to implement.  The other, called "External Axes" allows any configuration of subplots you choose.

[**Click here to read more about subplots in mplfinance**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/markdown/subplots.md).

P.S.
Be sure to read the complete tutorials, for the two procedures for subplots, here:

- [**Panels**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/panels.ipynb)
- [**External Axes**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/external_axes.ipynb)

[Additional Information about positioning subplots can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66147746/when-using-external-axes-method-to-plot-multiple-candlestick-charts-using-mplfin/66148116#66148116)

There are also a number of other customizations [documented here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#contents-and-tutorials).

Comment: Very much appreciated Daniel, when attempting this once more using the guide I realised my mistake was not creating a Figure first which then enabled the .add_subplot option

Answer (score 0):

finplot neither supports IPython nor [Jupyter](https://github.com/highfestiva/finplot#what-it-is-not), but works well in plain Python. :)